# Disable fetching of p2 repository indexes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

We're currently setting up maven and tycho to build eclipse plugins. Following the examples and documentations, we added some repositories with layout `p2` like this:

```
<repository>
  <id>eclipse-indigo</id>
  <layout>p2</layout>
  <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo</url>
</repository>
```

Now, everytime we execute the pom, maven is "fetching" p2 indexes which takes quite a while. We see a lot of lines like

```
[INFO] Fetching p2.index (0B of 96B at 0B/s) from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/
```

and it take some significant time until it actually starts the build or clean or whatever.

Is there a way to disable the fetching, at least temporarily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use maven offline mode (commandline switch -o)

For details see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357357